# When key in maps is an object how do I search by that object's attribute?

Tags: java, methods, hashmap, maps

So let's say I have a class Person and made a few objects of that class. Then I make a map which holds Person as Key and a String as Value. I want to make a method which takes a name and looks for a Person with that name and then prints out the value of the Key which had that name

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Ex03{

public static void main(String[] args) {

    new Ex03();

}

public Ex03(){

    Person person1 = new Person("Name1", "LastName1", "Address1");
    Person person2 = new Person("Name2", "LastName2", "Address2");
    Person person3 = new Person("Name3", "LastName3", "Address3");
    Person person4 = new Person("Name4", "LastName4", "Address4");

    Map<Person, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(person1, "12345678901");
    map.put(person2, "12345678902");
    map.put(person3, "12345678903");
    map.put(person4, "12345678904");

    findNumber(map, "Name1");

}

public void findNumber(Map<Person, String> map, String name){

}


class Person {
    String name, lastName, address;

    public Person(){

    }

    public Person(String name, String lastName, String address){

        this.name = name;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.address = address;

    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person [name=" + name + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", address=" + address + "]";
    }



} //end of class Person

}
```

How do I make the method findNumber() ?
Recap: Enter a string name, method finds a Person object which has that name, prints out the value that is bound to the Person Key which has the name we entered. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Unless you store a separate map of names to `Person` objects, you have to loop through the [`keySet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet--) of the map, comparing each key to the string.

Answer (score 0):

> Then I make a map which holds Person as Key and a String as Value. I
>   want to make a method which takes a name and looks for a Person with
>   that name and then prints out the value of the Key which had that name

Both of your requirements are contradictory, so to make it simpler, you can actually store key as `name` value  as `Person` object and value as key (i.e., but you are doing it reverse order) in the `HashMap`.

**Option (1): name as Key and Person as Value in HashMap**

This is what in general we do i.e., mapping objects to a simple key like String, Integer, etc.

```
Map<String,Person> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("John", person1);
//add other objects
```

Now look at `findNumber()` below:

```
public void findNumber(Map<Person, String> map, String name){
    Person person = map.get(name);
}
```

**Option (2): Person as key and name as Value in HashMap**

```
Map<Person, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(person1, "John");
//add other objects
```

Now look at `findNumber()` below:

```
public void findNumber(Map<Person, String> map, String name){
      Set<Person> keys = map.keySet();
        for(Person person : keys) {
            if(person.getName().equals(name)) {
                String name = map.get(person);
                break;
            }
        }
}
```

For this option (2) to work, you need to **override `equals()` and `hashcode()` inside your `Person` class**.

Also, as a side note, remember that **constructors are meant for initialization of instance variables and you are writing too much of logic inside constructors** inside your code (like `Ex03()`), which is not best practice.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as below...

```
public Ex03(){

    Person person1 = new Person("Name1", "LastName1", "Address1");
    Person person2 = new Person("Name2", "LastName2", "Address2");
    Person person3 = new Person("Name3", "LastName3", "Address3");
    Person person4 = new Person("Name4", "LastName4", "Address4");

    Map<String, Person> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("Name1", person1); // or map.put(person1.name, person1);
    map.put("Name2", person2);
    map.put("Name3", person3);
    map.put("Name4", person4);

    findPerson(map, "Name1");

}

public Person findPerson(Map<String, Person> map, String name){
    Person person = map.get(name);
}
```

**Edit:**

If you want to store number of person then you should add it in your person class as below.

```
public Ex03(){

    Person person1 = new Person("Name1", "LastName1", "Address1", "12345678901");
    Person person2 = new Person("Name2", "LastName2", "Address2", "12345678902");
    Person person3 = new Person("Name3", "LastName3", "Address3", "12345678903");
    Person person4 = new Person("Name4", "LastName4", "Address4", "12345678904");

    Map<String, Person> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("Name1", person1); // or map.put(person1.name, person1);
    map.put("Name2", person2);
    map.put("Name3", person3);
    map.put("Name4", person4);

    String number = findNumber(map, "Name1");

}

public String findNumber(Map<String, Person> map, String name){
    String number = map.get(name).number;
}

class Person {
    String name, lastName, address, number;

    public Person(){

    }

    public Person(String name, String lastName, String address, String number){

        this.name = name;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.address = address;
        this.number = number;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person [name=" + name + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", address=" + address + ", number=" + number"]";
    }     

} //end of class Person
```